# No puedo acceder a mysql

Tags: mysql

Que tal quiero entrar al workbench de MySQL o abrir el servidor desde cmd

`mysql -u root -p` y cuando pongo la contraseña me dice

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

Comment: ¿Estás escribiendo correctamente la contraseña?

Comment: si si uso la de siempre

Comment: El error es por que introduces una contraseña y seguro no es requerida

Comment: te adjunto este link de stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944936/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y

Answer (score 1):

Dependiendo de tu versión:
MYSQL < 5.7:
La contraseña queda en blanco, pudiendo ingresar simplemente con:

```
mysql -u root
```

al entarar cambia la contraseña:

```
mysqladmin -u root password [nuevacontraseña]
```

y con esto pudes acceder con cualquier administrador o conexión

Comment: Eso es así, cuando lo instalas en Linux o Windows te pide una contraseña, pero no es que en determinadas versiones la contraseña no se pida

Comment: Ya pude arreglarlo por suerte. Muchas gracias!

Comment: de hecho el comando esta bien al parecer es otro error.